# Why did the author use a comma instead of 'and'?

Tags: usage, commas, lists

If we enumerate a list of things, do we put **and** (or **, and**) in front of the last thing? Why did the author use a comma instead of **and**?

> The difference of effect between books which are not literature and
> those which are is that while these amuse, entertain, and glance over
> the surface of the mind, those touch the deepest springs of being.
> Literature books touch us aesthetically, it is true. The emotion
> aroused is impersonal, and thus removed from the keen thrill which is
> born of actual experiences; but it depends upon **the same passions,
> the same characteristics, the same humanity,** that underlie the joys
> and sorrows of real life. It is because we are capable of passion and
> of disappointment that we are moved by the love and anguish of Romeo
> and Juliet, of Francesca and Paolo. Our emotion is not identical with
> that with which the heart throbs in personal love and grief; yet art
> which is genuine awakes emotion thoroughly genuine. Books of
> sensationalism and sentimentality may excite curiosity, or wonder, or
> amusement, or sham feelings; but they must have at least some spark of
> sacred fire before they can arouse in the intelligent reader this
> inner throb of real feeling.

[Talks on the study of literature](https://%20https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=p6uBEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT18&lpg=PT18&dq=The%20emotion%20aroused%20is%20impersonal,%20and%20thus%20removed%20from%20the%20keen%20thrill%20which%20is%20born%20of%20actual%20experiences;%20but%20it%20depends%20upon%20the%20same%20passions,%20the%20same%20characteristics,%20the%20same%20humanity,%20that%20underlie%20the%20joys%20and%20sorrows%20of%20real%20life.&source=bl&ots=JQWmkIXXUL&sig=ACfU3U3knTN-Ygkh-vM0JO__Vse696t9IQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXlJ3rp9P_AhVOplYBHWCkBUUQ6AF6BAgHEAM#v=onepage&q=The%20emotion%20aroused%20is%20impersonal%2C%20and%20thus%20removed%20from%20the%20keen%20thrill%20which%20is%20born%20of%20actual%20experiences%3B%20but%20it%20depends%20upon%20the%20same%20passions%2C%20the%20same%20characteristics%2C%20the%20same%20humanity%2C%20that%20underlie%20the%20joys%20and%20sorrows%20of%20real%20life.&f=false)

Comment: This is a rhetorical device called “asyndeton”. Famously used in the Gettysburg address or Churchill’s “We shall fight on the beaches” address. It looks like there are many other questions here on ELL about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is conjunction "and" selective in certain situation?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/296545/is-conjunction-and-selective-in-certain-situation)

Comment: Thank you. One more question. Why is a comma there before ***that***?

Comment: You are right that it’s not required, but my guess would be that this is a transcription of a speech where particularly strong emphasis was put on that last point (“the same humanity”), and so the comma indicates a pause was taken there.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, Mr. Murphy.